# Modelsim Warning: "does not denote a port"

Tags: warnings, vhdl, modelsim

I am simulation the LEON3 with modelsim. After a **make vsim** I get a do-file I use for calling modelsim.
It gives me a warning message and I don't know if this message now is relevant. Actually I don't know what it means.

```
# ** Warning: [6] /path/to/lib/tech/ec/orca/orca.vhd(14744): (vcom-1288) VITAL timing generic "tpd_a1_s2" port specification "s2" does not denote a port.
```

The indicated code:

```
ENTITY fadsu2 IS
   GENERIC(
      TimingChecksOn : boolean := TRUE;
      XOn            : boolean := FALSE;
      MsgOn          : boolean := TRUE;
      InstancePath   : string := "fadsu2";
      tpd_a0_bco     : VitalDelayType01 := (0.001 ns, 0.001 ns);
      tpd_a1_bco     : VitalDelayType01 := (0.001 ns, 0.001 ns);
      tpd_b0_bco     : VitalDelayType01 := (0.001 ns, 0.001 ns);
      tpd_b1_bco     : VitalDelayType01 := (0.001 ns, 0.001 ns);
      tpd_bci_bco    : VitalDelayType01 := (0.001 ns, 0.001 ns);
      tpd_con_bco    : VitalDelayType01 := (0.001 ns, 0.001 ns);
      tpd_a0_s0      : VitalDelayType01 := (0.001 ns, 0.001 ns);
      tpd_a0_s1      : VitalDelayType01 := (0.001 ns, 0.001 ns);
      tpd_a1_s0      : VitalDelayType01 := (0.001 ns, 0.001 ns);
      tpd_a1_s1      : VitalDelayType01 := (0.001 ns, 0.001 ns);
     tpd_a1_s2      : VitalDelayType01 := (0.001 ns, 0.001 ns); -- <--- here
      tpd_b0_s0      : VitalDelayType01 := (0.001 ns, 0.001 ns);
      tpd_b0_s1      : VitalDelayType01 := (0.001 ns, 0.001 ns);
      tpd_b1_s0      : VitalDelayType01 := (0.001 ns, 0.001 ns);
      tpd_b1_s1      : VitalDelayType01 := (0.001 ns, 0.001 ns);
      tpd_bci_s0     : VitalDelayType01 := (0.001 ns, 0.001 ns);
      tpd_bci_s1     : VitalDelayType01 := (0.001 ns, 0.001 ns);
      tpd_con_s0     : VitalDelayType01 := (0.001 ns, 0.001 ns);
      tpd_con_s1     : VitalDelayType01 := (0.001 ns, 0.001 ns);
      tipd_a0        : VitalDelayType01 := (0.0 ns, 0.0 ns);
      tipd_a1        : VitalDelayType01 := (0.0 ns, 0.0 ns);
      tipd_b0        : VitalDelayType01 := (0.0 ns, 0.0 ns);
      tipd_b1        : VitalDelayType01 := (0.0 ns, 0.0 ns);
      tipd_bci       : VitalDelayType01 := (0.0 ns, 0.0 ns);
      tipd_con       : VitalDelayType01 := (0.0 ns, 0.0 ns));

   PORT(
      a0             :  IN    std_logic;
      a1             :  IN    std_logic;
      b0             :  IN    std_logic;
      b1             :  IN    std_logic;
      bci            :  IN    std_logic;
      con            :  IN    std_logic;
      bco            :  OUT   std_logic;
      s0             :  OUT   std_logic;
      s1             :  OUT   std_logic);

   ATTRIBUTE Vital_Level0 OF fadsu2 : ENTITY IS TRUE;

END fadsu2;
```

any sugestions?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be an s2 in your port.  From the IEEE Std 1076.4-1995 4.3.2.1.3.1 Propagation delay "A timing generic beginning with the prefix tpd is a backannotation timing generic representing propagation delay associated with the specified input-to-output delay path".  You generic and port declarations appear to not match.  Comment it out and see what breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I happened to have a copy of that source laying around.  Comment out the offending line mentioning `tpd_a1_s2` and it will compile.

Without modification:

```
david_koontz@Macbook: ghdl -a fadsu2.vhdl  
fadsu2.vhdl:23:7:warning: 's2' is not a port name (in VITAL generic name)
```

Commenting out the offending generic:

```
david_koontz@Macbook: ghdl -a fadsu2.vhdl  
david_koontz@Macbook:
```

And it analyzes.  (I extracted the entity and architecture pair for `fadsu2` from `orca.vhd`)

The issue is that you have a tpd value (time propagation delay) specified between input `a1` and output `s2` (`tpd_a1_s2`), where output port `s2` is non-existent.